# Finding multiple occuring of word in string in Python

Tags: python, string, find

So I have a string that contains data below

> https://myanimelist.net/animelist/domis1/load.json?status=2&offset=0.

I want to find all 'anime_id' and put them into the list (only numbers).
I tried with find('anime_id'), but I can't do this for multiple occurings in the string.

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Comment: Hint: json is a list of dictionaries. Loop through the list entries, and extract the dictionary key (anime_id)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, how to extract `anime_id` from a `json` file called `test.json`, using built-in `json` module:

```py
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Create generator and search for anime_id
gen = (i['anime_id'] for i in data)

# If needed, iterate over generator and create a list
gen_list = list(gen)

# Print list on console
print(gen_list)
```

Comment: `gen = [...]` is not a generator, it's a list. You need to use `()` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is in json format, you can parse it with the builtin `json` module.

```py
import json

data = json.loads(your_string)

for d in data:
    print(d["anime_id"])
```